# HIVE order by messes up data

Tags: hadoop, sql-order-by, hive, hiveql

In Hive 0.8 with Hadoop 1.03 consider this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  key int,
  date timestamp,
  name string,
  surname string,
  height int,
  weight int,
  age int) 
CLUSTERED BY(key) INTO 128 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Then I tried:

```
select *
from table
where key=xxx
order by date;
```

The result is sorted but everything after the column name is wrong.  In fact, all the rows have the exact same values in the respective fields and the surname column is missing.  I also have a bitmap index on name and surname and an index on key.

Is there something wrong with my query or should I be looking into bugs about order by (I cant find anything specific).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there has been an error in loading data into hive. Make sure you don't have any special characters in your CSV File that might interfere with the insertion.

And you have clustered by the key property. Where does this key come from the CSV? or some other source? Are you sure that this is unique?

Comment: If i try the same query without the order by then the results are just fine. So it cant be any special character issue. The key is unique yes.